# Flutter : Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 3: 3

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am building a simple Todoapplication. Code is copied mainly from https://zapp.run/edit/riverpod-todo-app-zv2060sv306?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

```
class TodoItemView extends HookConsumerWidget{
  const TodoItemView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final index = ref.watch(itemIdProvider);
    print("building for index inside child ${index}");

    final todo = ref.watch(todosProvider.select((value) => value[index]));

    
    return ListTile(
      leading: Checkbox(
        value: todo.isCompleted,
        onChanged: (value) {
          ref.read(todosProvider.notifier).toggle(todo);
        },
      ),
      title: Text(todo.description),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
        onPressed: () {
          ref.read(todosProvider.notifier).removeTodo(todo);
          
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of ListView. When I try to remove any item from todolist. It causes the following error.

```
class TodoListView extends HookConsumerWidget{
  const TodoListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print("building list view ");


    
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: ref.watch(todosProvider.select((value) => value.length)),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // as it comes down, reads all tasks lists again
        print("building for index ${index}");
        return ProviderScope(
          overrides: [
            itemIdProvider.overrideWith((ref){
              ref.onDispose(() { print("disposing item id provider " );});
              print("index ${index}");
              return index;
              
            }
              
            ),],
          child: TodoItemView(key: UniqueKey()));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 3: 3
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/js_array.dart 591:7                 _get]
packages/webapp/home.dart 99:51                                                   selector
```

which is understandable since we are watching index till 3 originally but after deletion, we should have only 3 elements and hence the error. Not able to resolve it though. If I use `ref.read` instead of `ref.watch` then it doesn't refresh the widget state. COuld anyone please help?

I am expecting it to run smoothly.

Comment: You are trying to read an invalid index , for your case you can reduce the index number by one. `(value) => value[index-1]));`

Comment: No, it works fine with original length : 4. It goes till index 3 for the first time but when I remove the item, new length becomes 3 and index should go to 2. Since we are watching the provider on `value[index]`. It never got a chance to dispose. So, question remains, is there a way to dispose `ref.watch` without disposing the underlying provider